# How to redefine -top-level-division in pandoc for each constituent file separately?

Tags: text, markdown, pandoc, m4

I have a bunch of `.md` constituent content files marked up with headers `#`, `##`, etc.

I want to flexibly compile new documents, with constituent files unchanged but residing at different levels of ToC hierarchy of the final document.

For example:

1. In `compiled-1.pdf`, top-level header `# Foo` from `constituent-1.md` might end up as "Chapter Foo" --- no change to its level in hierarchy.
2. However, in `compiled-2.pdf`, the very same `# Foo` from the very same `constituent-1.md` might end up as "Section Foo" --- a demotion to level 2 in the ToC hierarchy of `compiled-2.pdf`.

In each constituent `.md` file the top level header is always `#` and each constituent `.md` file is always treated as a whole indivisible unit. Therefore, all of a constituent file's headers are to be demoted by the same factor. Also, a constituent file's headers are never promoted.

I feel the problem has to do with re-setting `-top-level-divison` for each file. How to do it properly (using `.yaml` configs and `make`)?

But maybe a better way is to create for each final document a master file that establishes a hierarchy of constituent files with a combination of `include ('constituent-1.md')` etc. and `define ('level', '1')` etc. Such master file would then be pre-processed with `m4` to search and replace `#` with `##` or `###` etc., according to each file's `level`, and then piped to `pandoc`.

What's the best approach?

Answer (score 3):

I think these are the right ideas, but not the right tools. Instead of using m4, you might want to check out [pandoc filters](https://pandoc.org/filters.html), especially the built-in [Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) or the excellent [panflute](http://scorreia.com/software/panflute/) python package. These allow you to manipulate the actual document structure instead of just the text representation.

E.g., this Lua filter demotes all headers in a document:

```lua
function Header (header)
  header.level = header.level + 1
  return header
end
```

Similarly, you could define your own include statement based on code blocks:

````
```{include="FILENAME.md"}
```
````

Include with this filter:

```lua
function CodeBlock (cb)
  if not cb.attributes.include then
    return
  end
  local fh = io.open(cb.attributes.include)
  local blocks = pandoc.read(fh:read('*a')).blocks
  f:close()
  return blocks
end
```

It is also possible to apply a filter to only a subset of blocks (requires a little hack):

```lua
local blocks = …
local div = pandoc.Div(blocks)
local filtered_blocks = pandoc.walk_block(div, YOUR_FILTER).content
```

You can combine and extend these building blocks to write your own filter and define your extensions. This way, one can have a main document which includes all your sub-files and shifts header levels as necessary.